# A question about the degree of sin(2π/n) over the rationals

Tags: cyclotomic-polynomials

In cyclotomic theory, $\cos (2\pi /n)$) is shown to have degree $\varphi (n)/2$ over the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$, while $\sin (2\pi /n)$has degree $\varphi (n)$ (as long as n is not divisible by 4).$Cos(2\pi /n)=(\zeta +{{\zeta }^{-1}})/2$ where $\zeta$ is a primitive root of unity in the nth cyclotomic field,  so $\mathbb{Q}(2\cos (2\pi /n))$= $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta +{{\zeta }^{-1}})$ and this extension field has degree 2 over $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta )$and hence degree $\varphi (n)/2 $ over $\mathbb{Q}$. The extension field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta +{{\zeta }^{-1}})$  is sometimes called the maximal real extension of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta )$.

$Sin(2\pi /n)=(\zeta -{{\zeta }^{-1}})/i$ so the matching extension field is $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta -{{\zeta }^{-1}})$which is totally complex and this extension is the maximal complex extension. When n is not divisible by 4 only the identity map ${{\sigma }_{{{1}_{{}}}}}:\zeta \to {{\zeta }^{1}}$ fixes $\zeta  - {\zeta ^{ - 1}}$, so this extension is degree 1 over $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta )$ and hence degree $\varphi (n)$over $\mathbb{Q}$ as stated above.

But as a vector space $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta )$is the direct sum of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta +{{\zeta }^{-1}})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta -{{\zeta }^{-1}})$ and since $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta +{{\zeta }^{-1}})$ is degree $\varphi (n)/2$over $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta -{{\zeta }^{-1}})$ should also be degree $\varphi (n)/2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, yet the degree of sine over $\mathbb{Q}$is $\varphi (n)$ (I suspect the issue is that $\sin (2\pi /n)$is really in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta ,i)$.)

Comment: What do you think the dimension of $V\oplus W$ is, in terms of the dimensions of $V$ and $W$? And what do you mean by ${\bf Q}_n$?

Comment: Thank you for your comments Gerry, I should have mentioned that Qn was the nth cyclotomic field. Concerning your question, the dimension of the direct sum of vector spaces is always the sum of the dimensions and this is the source of the dilemma.

Comment: I see ${\bf Q}_n$ is gone. Anyway, I recommend you think about the simplest nontrivial example, $n=6$. The cosine is rational, the sine and the primitive 6th root have degree 2 but don't give the same extension. Think about how your direct sum works.

Comment: Yes, the case of n = 6 makes it clear that this is not a direct sum as extensions but as Q subspaces, so the correct direct sum is simply the real and imaginary parts of Q(ζ) - in which case there is no issue. Thanks Gerry - it does help to look at the trivial cases.

Comment: No worries. Maybe you could write up & post an answer, based on what you now know about the question.