# How to find the degree of $\sin(2\pi /n)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, cyclotomic-fields

Let $\zeta$ be the n-th primitive unit root. with not too much effort I have proved that $\cos(2\pi /n)$ has degree $\varphi (n)/2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, but failed to the degree of $\sin(2\pi /n)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

> I can myself only proof  that $\sin(2\pi /n)=(\zeta -{{\zeta }^{-1}})/2i$, but don't know how to proceed . I am waiting for your help, thank you!

I have searched this website and find a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1352274/a-question-about-the-degree-of-sin2%CF%80-n-over-the-rationals), but that seems doesn't solve this problem, I need some detail about this quesion.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't solve this problem"? It does.

Comment: Not "the" but "**a**" primitive root.

Comment: yes , I should say "a". I don't know what he means by saying :$Sin(2\pi /n)=(\zeta -{{\zeta }^{-1}})/i$ so the matching extension field is $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta -{{\zeta }^{-1}})$

Comment: Would you please show me some details and post as an answer?@DonAntonio

Comment: I present two approaches for solving a specific case of the $\cos(2\pi/n)$ problem in the link below.  The first approach might be tough to adapt given the generality of "$n$", but the Galois-theoretic approach generalizes nicely if you can determine the elements of $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)/\mathbb{Q})$ in terms of their action on $\zeta$.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2230280/find-the-degree-of-extension-bbb-q%CE%B6-9-%CE%B6%E2%88%921-9-over-bbb-q/2230302#2230302

Comment: @王李远 You can read in section 3, page 5 of the following all about this: http://www2.oberlin.edu/faculty/jcalcut/tanpap.pdf

Comment: Thank you very very much for providing such useful and rich materials !!! I will take time to study that @DonAntonio